# RichFaces fileUpload unable to invoke listener randomly

Tags: file-upload, richfaces

I am facing a problem using richfaces. I have a .jsp page where I'm using rich:fileUpload in it. When I upload the excel file, it should fill the datatable with corresponding values. On the localhost it works perfectly. Whenever I try it on the website, it works 90-95% of the times. I've been trying all day many solutions to try finding out the source of this bug but it's hopeless.
Can anybody help me please?

```
            <h:form>    
                <table>                 
                    <tr>                      
                      <td>
                         <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadToolBB.fileUploadListener}" id="uploadFile" ajaxSingle="true" allowFlash="false"
                                     immediateUpload="false" listHeight="57px" listWidth="485px"  maxFilesQuantity="1"  acceptedTypes="xlsx"  
                                     noDuplicate="true" doneLabel="The file has been successfully uploaded" validatorMessage="An error occured while uploading the file">
                                <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="exceptionPanel,dataLst,uploadFile,fileName" oncomplete="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('importPanel');"/>
                                <a4j:support event="onclear" reRender="uploadFile" />
                                <f:facet name="label">
                                    <h:outputText value="{_KB}KB from {KB}KB uploaded --- {mm}:{ss}" /> 
                                </f:facet>
                        </rich:fileUpload>
                      </td>
                    </tr>                       
                </table>
            </h:form>
```

When we click on upload the datatable should be filled with values, however it's not..no error is shown in the logs, all I could get is that it didn't invoke the fileUploadListener method in the bean.

```
public void fileUploadListener(UploadEvent event) 
{
  try {
      UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();
      includedFabsHM.clear();
      selecedUploadHist.setFileName(item.getFileName());
      FctUploadedFileVO uploadedFile = new FctUploadedFileVO();
      uploadedFile.setFile(item.getData());
      selecedUploadHist.setUploadedFile(uploadedFile);

      uploadToStagingTable(item.getData());

      if(selecedUploadHist.getUploadHistoryId()!=0)
      {
          newFileUploaded = true;  
      }

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        FacesUtil.handleFPException(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `it should fill the datatable with corresponding values` doesn't tell us anything, moreso when this is done by your code we know nothing about. Show the relevant code and describe what's happening, as opposed to what you expect to happen.

Comment: I've added some code

Comment: Can't help with RF 3 I'm afraid, unless something went wrong with the request there shouldn't be a reason not to call the listener